# Left align currency symbol but right align the number in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, formatting

Is there any way to Left align currency symbol but right align the number in LWC?

Example:

$    2500.38
$      127.63
$        99.01

Comment: what is the context? Datatable? regular html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
<div  style="width:10%;">
    <p>
        <span>$</span><span style="float:right">12.23</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>$</span><span style="float:right">454.23</span>
    </p>
</div>
```